# How to write a given element of the orthogonal group as a product of reflections

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, quadratic-forms, classical-groups

Let $V$ be a 3-dimensional vector space over a finite field $F$ of $q$ elements, where $q$ is an odd prime power. We know that the orthogonal group $O(V)$ is generated by reflections. How can a given element of $O(V)$ (in particular of $SO(V)$) be written explicitly as a product of reflections? For example, let $e,f,d$ be a standard basis for $V$, where $(e,e)=(f,f)=(e,d)=(e,f)=0$, $(e,f)=1$, $(d,d)=1$, and let $g\in SO(V)$ be the element which sends $e\to -e$, $f\to -f$, $d\to d+e$.

What would be the procedure of expressing such an element as a product of reflections? I have tried combining some randoms reflections together, but I haven't been able to find an expression for $g$, so I was wondering if there is a method to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: $g(g(d)=g(d+e)=d+e-e=d$, and $g$ is a reflection.

Comment: If you send the unit vector $d$ to $e + f$, which are orthogonal unit vectors, the squared length of the resulting vector is $\|e \|^2 + 2\langle e, f \rangle + \|f\|^2 = \|e\|^2 + \|f\|^2 = 2$, so your map is not length-preserving, hence not in $SO(3)$. You'll never be able to write that as a product of reflections, because they *are* all length-preserving.

Comment: @John Sorry, I don't seem to understand your comment - I am sending $d$ to $d+e$ not $e+f$...

Comment: @Thomas I know that $g(g(d))=d$ but how does that show that $g$ is a reflection? Which vector is $g$ a reflection in?

Comment: $g\circ g= id$ means that $g$ is either a line symmetry or a reflelxion but the determinant of your matrix is 1.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the reply. I am not sure what a line symmetry is. Also since $g$ has determinant $1$ it cannot be a reflection since any reflection has determinant $-1$.

Comment: Replace my remark about $e+f$ with $d+e$; that vector *also* has length $\sqrt{2}$. So your map still can't be in $SO(3)$.

Comment: In the base $e,f, d+g(d)$ the matrix is $diag(-1,-1,1)$. So you can write it as the product of $diag(-1,1,1)$ and $diag(1,-1,1)$

Comment: @Thomas But then $diag(-1,1,1)$ and $diag(1,-1,1)$ are not reflections since a reflection is of the form $r_{v}: x \to x - \frac{(x,v)}{Q(v)}v$ and those two diagonal matrices cannot be written in that form.

Answer (score 2):

One answer is "first find a 2D invariant subspace". Typically you'd do thus by looking at the characteristic polynomial, factoring over the reals, and each quadratic factor will have a pair of conjugate eigenvalues, and these will determined a 2-dimensional (or 2k-dimensional) subspace.

Then you solve the problem on that 2D subspace, and then recursively on the complementary $n-2$-dimensional subspace.

For a 2D rotation, to rotate $e_1$ to $v = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ via two reflections, you can reflect about the axis at angle $\theta/2$, and then reflect about $v$. This takes $e_1$ to $v$, and then $v$ to $v$, and hence the composition takes $e_1$ to $v$. And since it's a rotation of the plane, it has to be the right one.

Alternatively, and probably more simply, you just look up a description of using Householder reflections to do a QR factorization of your matrix. Trefethen and Bao's *Numerical Linear Algebra* has a nice description in "Lecture 10".

Comment: The matrix for $g$ in this case is already upper triangular. How do you get the factorisation into reflections after doing the QR factorisation?

Comment: I didn't say "do a QR factorization"; I said to use the algorithm that uses Householder transforms to build a QR factorization; that algorithm writes $Q$ as a product of $Q_i$, each of which is a reflection. For an element of $SO(3)$, the $QR$ factorization will always produce $R = I$. (Another reason that your matrix $g$ is evidently not orthogonal!)